# Broadcast BLE advertisement with custom data from Raspberry Pi Zero W using it as Peripheral

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi-zero, bluetooth-peripheral

Okay, I know my question is way too broad but I'm really stuck. I'm trying to simply broadcast some custom message e.g. "HELLO BLE WRLD" every second from a Raspberry Pi Zero W via Bluetooth for the sake of POC. I'm failing miserably. I don't need to be able to connect to the RPi, just detect the Advertisement data and read the message in it.

Is there a way I can achieve this with a running Java app?